# SQLite find total number of elements matching specific name in row.

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite db for movie information. 
if I pull just say films containing a genre of comedy how do I find out how many I pulled with the genre of comedy

pseudo code

```
 rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE genre = "Action"');
 var size = number.of.elements.in.rs
```

Comment: vidario gave you the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mydb WHERE genre = 'Action'

Comment: Try console.log(the result variable) and check your browser console to check the details of the object returned.